# Specific Application Insights ingestion sampling

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a question about Application Insights ingestion sampling. I want to apply sampling to only the "Dependency" event type. Is there a way to specify the sampling on a single event type.

Comment: so what's your project,  `.net core web app`, or others? As far as I know, ingestion sampling is not supported sampling on a single event type.

Comment: its a .net core web ap

Answer (score 1):

For ingestion sampling, it does not support sampling on a single event type. It only apply to all events.

You can consider using the other 2 sampling like adaptive sampling or fixed sampling via your code.